# Detect unneeded headers in a C file - GCC

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Is there a way to remove unnecessary header files in my C file?

I can comment each header and check for implicit declaration warnings.

But technically, i feel GCC should be having some extension to enable this check. Please let me know.